# SCSS: change color of link inside of block (on block hover)

Tags: css, sass

Can I use this code (SCSS):

```
#block {
  &:hover {
    #link_inside_of_block {
      new style for link in the block: on block hover;
    }  
  }
}
```

I've written this code, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#block {
  #link_inside_of_block {
    &:hover {
      new style for link in the block: on block hover;
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: This is just wrong. Ofc you can use any valid css selector as descendants to a `:hover` pseudo selector.

Comment: Ronald had this introductory sentence in his answer pre-editing: *"This wont work because you are not allowed to put id's or classes inside hover tags."*. This is what my comment referred to.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
#block {
  &:hover {
    #link_inside_of_block {
      color: #000;

      &:hover {
        color: red;
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

This will generate to:

```
#block:hover #link_inside_of_block {
  color: #000;
}

#block:hover #link_inside_of_block:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

You can play around on SassMeister. Have a look at my [sample](http://sassmeister.com/gist/3c24ab0e2c67d40d2547)